# Создание ботов для соц сетей

Tags: c++, python, любой-язык, бот

На каком языке лучше всего реализовывать ботов? Сейчас в тренде явно Python, но хотелось бы понять по каким причинам так, ведь по идее, практически на любом ЯП можно реализовать бота, практически с любым функционалом. Например на том же C++, Java. В чем особенность и превосходство Python'a над другими языками?

Comment: По моему мнению лучше всего взять Python, т. к. 1) Простой язык 2) Практически в каждой соц. сети уже готов API для Python

Comment: Хотел написать развёрнутый ответ, но оказалось в интернете прям много информации как раз об этом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Питон обладает:

- Элегантым синтаксисом (отчасти благодаря динамичeскoй типизации)
- Большим количеством библиотек, а например вот библиотеки для телеграмм бота:
  [1](https://pypi.org/project/python-telegram-bot/) [2](https://pypi.org/project/pyTelegramBotAPI/)
- Легок в изучении и популярен.

**P.S** Хотя в принципе можно писать на любом языке.

Comment: автор PHP слабый, а у Python типизация динамичeская

Comment: @finally Ну вообще да, только это две разные дихотомии.